# Facebook PHP SDK showing not logged in

Tags: php, facebook

I am new to facebook PHP SDK, I am logged into facebook, but when I run the example.php file, it always shows me logged out.

when I tried following code:

```
require '../src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'XXXXX',//I am using my own APP ID and KEY
  'secret' => 'XXXXX',
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

echo var_dump($facebook);
```

It is giving me following output:

```
object(Facebook)[1]
  protected 'appId' => string 'XXXXXX' (length=15)
  protected 'appSecret' => string 'XXXXXXX' (length=32)
  protected 'user' => int 0
  protected 'signedRequest' => null
  protected 'state' => string '151c32d04cd0175f24292bda479a2d45' (length=32)
  protected 'accessToken' => string '253401284678598|80fa394218494b87c2f96640da5a32eb' (length=48)
  protected 'fileUploadSupport' => boolean false
```

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

You must check if userid is empty and redirect him to login url.

```
if(!$user) {
 $dialog_url= "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
    . "client_id=" . FB_APP_ID
    . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirect_url)
    . "&scope=" . implode(',', $permissions);
    exit("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url ."'</script>");

}
```

FB_APP_ID is your appid

$redirect_url can be your page tab, canvas app or website depending on your needs where you want the user to land after givving you permissions.

$permissions is an array with the permissions you need. Remove `. implode(',', $permissions)` if you want just basic permissions.

Comment: But why does it shows that I am not logged in? Why the SDK is not taking my session ?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing p3p headers causing your browser not to accept cookies from Facebook on your site.  See: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceOfP3PAndACompactPrivacyPolicy.aspx for more information.